# How to add dynamic content to backbone collection Dashboard?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I have a Dashboard 
I load collections that add  to the DashBoard view : these are my widgets.

This works.

Now I need to load dynamically inside each div a content (widget content). Each widget is very different (charts, chat, picture, parameters...)

What would be the best strategy to add these widgets to the dashboard ?

I use requireJS to dynamically add content.

Structure  I useed is:

app.dashboard

regards